# Multiple test assemblies in Visual Studio solution file

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I have a single visual studio solution containning all the projects (lets say there are five projects). Additionally, the solution also contains test projects for each of the source projects. In all, there are 10 projects under a single solution. When I launch the test view in visual studio it lists tests only from one of the test assemblies. It should display tests from all the test assemblies.

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was my mistake. The tests that were not listed on the test view, where part of the test project that were not compiling (compilation failure). Once I fixed the compilation failure, I was able to view all the tests from different assemblies in a single test view.

My fault.

Answer (score 0):

Does it only list the tests related to the 'startup project' ?